# Android - Access child of gridview that is not on screen

Tags: android

Is it possible to access a child view of a *gridview* that is not on screen and change it?

I have tried using *getCount()* when iterating over the gridview, but when it reaches the children that are not visible(on screen display) they lose their type (they should be ImageViews) and I can not do anything with them; I want to change their image.

An snippet of code;

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
Integer items = gridView.getCount();
Log.d(TAG, "1)child count::"+((ViewGroup)gridView).getChildCount());
Log.d(TAG, "2)get count::"+items);
for (int i=0; i < items; ++i) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)gridView).getChildAt(i);
    if (nextChild instanceof ImageView) {
        Log.i(TAG, i+" is imageview");
        ((ImageView) nextChild).setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, i+" is NOT imageview");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the image resource in the adapter's `getView()` method. Then the code will run as and when they become visible, rather than trying to force it before they come into the screen.